# With SPIFFS or LittleFS, on an ESP8266, is it possible to write a filesystem to flash, and then later create/modify files from the firmware?

Tags: esp8266, spiffs

To clarify, I'm working on a project on an esp8266 (specifically an esp-12s using NodeMCU 1.0).

I have a bunch of html files and images that I bundle into a LittleFS binary that gets written to the flash using esptool (or the arduino ide, which uses esptool internally anyway).

To store the user's settings, I also create a file with the intention of serialising that data to the file.

Unfortunately it crashes and resets as soon as I call `LittleFS.open(path, "w");`.

So I just need to know, if I compile and upload a filesystem, is that filesystem "Read only"?

(If the answer is yes, then I know I need to use a different method to save user data, if it's no, then there's a bug in my code somewhere)

Comment: Strip down the code to the bare minimum such that the bug is still reproducible and share it in a new Q here.

Comment: If you're curious I found the bug, it was a buffer overrun, I was using far too small a statically allocated buffer for something. It just happened to be crashing when I tried to open a file for writing, and everything else appeared to be working completely fine. So @romkey's answer was able to get my head out of the trees and see the forest for what it was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, a filesystem image written to flash is not read-only. It's usable exactly as if it had been created by the firmware. There is no discernible difference to the software running on the ESP8266.